# R, hypothesis testing and Z score

Tags: r

In learning of hypothesis testing, I want to see if different gender has the same survival rate.

By using Australian AIDS Survival Data

Here are my hypothesis statements:

```
Hº: Gender has no significant difference in survival
H1: Female has better chance of survival
```

I want to calculate the Z score to test the hypothesis. In R:

```
a.data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/csv/MASS/Aids2.csv")
female_data <- subset(a.data, a.data$sex == "F")

#function for z test
z.test2 = function(a, b, n){
  sample_mean = mean(a)
  pop_mean = mean(b)
  c = nrow(n)
  zeta = (sample_mean - pop_mean) / (sd(b) / sqrt(c))
  return(zeta)
}

z.test2(as.numeric(female_data$status), as.numeric(a.data$status), female_data)
```

The Z score is -0.4645053

As the Z score is between -1.96 and +1.96, the p-value will be larger than 0.05. so I can’t reject the null hypothesis.

Am I doing the right thing in hypothesis testing? If not, where's the problem?

If the null hypothesis is “Female has a better survival rate”, how shall I change the testing process?

Thank you.

Comment: `If the null hypothesis is “Female has a better survival rate”, how shall I change the testing process?` This is not a correct null hypothesis. A null hypothesis always assumes the absence of a relationship. The way you stated your hypotheses above is correct.

Comment: @headpoint, for example, is there a R built-in function, or other means to calculate the Z score?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want to test two null hypotheses:

- **H_0a**: no association between female and survival
- **H_0b**: positive relationship between female and survival.

You should refrain from using **H_1** to denote a null hypothesis as this is usually used to refer to a an alternative hypothesis (the alternative is what you want to show, the null is what you want to disprove).

What you call the *population mean* is not really the population mean. It is the sample mean of both groups and therefore random. This renders the standard error that you compute incorrect.

One way to get a correct standard error for the difference of the means in the two groups is to run the following regression

```
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/csv/MASS/Aids2.csv")
data$female <- as.integer(data$sex == "F")
data$alive <- as.integer(data$status == "A")
summary(lm(alive ~ female, data = data))
```

This will give you a test statistic of 0.472. The absolute value of this is less than 1.96 and you don't reject H_0a. 
Your null hypothesis H_0b can be tested by a one-sided t-test. The test statistic is less than  1.65 (0.95 quantile of standard normal) and you will not reject H_0b.

Please note that you should never test these two hypotheses in this order without adjusting for multiple testing.

Comment: I am afraid that for a binary outcome linear regression is very unlikely to be appropriate.

Comment: The usual argument against linear regression doesn't apply here, since the regressor is also binary and OLS will just fit the sample means. This is just a neat way for getting a standard error for the difference of the means.

Comment: @AndreasDzemski, Dear Mr.Dzemski, thank you so much helping me in this question. it points out my mistake and show me the right way. Your input benefits the learning journey! However, as a beginner, I am not able to tell if it’s the most proper way to solve this problem. (as another comment concerns). Another answer is a little easier for me to understand.

Comment: If I can choose both for the answers, I will certainly do it. Would you mind I choose the other as the answer? Please don’t feel uncomfortable, your help plays a very important role in this world.

Comment: Sure, go ahead. My intent was to show you a correct way to approach the problem that is similar to your original approach (compute a Z-score) and that allows you to test your one-sided hypothesis.

Comment: @AndreasDzemski, thank you for the kind understanding. :)

Answer (score 1):

Chi-Squared Test of Independence should do for your binomial response:

```
H0=same proportions of survival for the sexes 
H1=different survival rates for the sexes (indicating gender variable dependence)

chisq.test(table(sex=a.data$sex,status=a.data$status))


   ##   Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
   ## 
   ## data:  table(sex = a.data$sex, status = a.data$status)
   ##X-squared = 0.13041, df = 1, p-value = 0.718
```

The p-value suggests that no significant difference was found and hence you did not find evidence to reject H0, the hypothesis of independence.